# Error on meteor project setup

Tags: meteor

I setup meteor environment

meteor create todoapp
cd todoapp
Then write meteor and press enter after then I run on localhost:3000 then I  receive following error on terminal

```
Exception from sub meteor_autoupdate_clientVersions id fRm2pMK35Ji2uPut5 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'OneOf' of undefined
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and format it properly?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's pretty hard to tell what went wrong here. You might try a `npm install`, and see if it's missing dependencies. What else have you tried?

Comment: I not make any change just create and then start and then when I run localhost:3000 on browser this error appear

Comment: Could you run `meteor --version` and show its output?

Comment: Styx yes sir it give this output  Meteor 1.5.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the actual reason of this issue any way I found a solution I uninstalled Meteor the reinstalled it after this the issue has been resolved.